# Why is the variance of a Bernoulli distribution the product of its probability of 'success' and 'failure'?

Tags: variance, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, variability

Can anyone explain in simple terms why the variance of a Bernoulli distribution is: Var[X] = p(1 – p)? More generally, why is the binomial distribution's variance the product of the number of trials, probability of success, and probability of failure, i.e. Var[X] = npq?

Thank you for explaining this in the most pragmatic way possible. It's very appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512889/why-is-the-variance-of-a-binomial-distribution-not-n2p1-p

Comment: Going back to basics, how do you define $\text{Var}(X)$? Start with this definition, and then see where that takes you.

Answer (score 3):

It is intuitive that the expectation of the variable is $p$, so that the deviations from $0$ and $1$ are linear functions of $p$. As the variance is the weighted sum of the squared deviations, the expression of the variance should be a cubic polynomial in $p$.

On another hand, when the probability is $0$, the distribution degenerates to a constant and the variance cancels. Also, the expression must be symmetrical around $p=\frac12$. So you can expect the variance to be proportional to $pq=p(1-p)$.

Then again by symmetry, the polynomial cannot be cubic. Taking $p=\frac12$, the variance is computed to be $\frac1{2^2}$. Finally,

$$\text{Var}[X]=pq$$

is the only possibility.

---

A Binomial variable is the sum of $n$ i.i.d. Bernouilli. As the variance is additive, that of the Binomial is

$$\text{Var}[Y]=n\,\text{Var}[X]=npq.$$

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: +1 -- this is pretty clever.  I can't explain the downvote, I'm afraid.

Comment: @jbowman That's unfair: I believe you haven't understood the argument. The point is that the variance has a degree *at most $3$* in $p$ because it's a sum of probabilities (linear in $p$) times squared deviations (and the deviations are linear in $p$). The second part of the argument establishes that the leading term cannot be $3$ and the symmetry also establishes it cannot be $1,$ whence--as is clearly concluded here--the variance is a *quadratic* function of $p.$ Although in this simple application such reasoning is unnecessary, it illustrates a powerful method for more complex cases.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't downvote, but my speculation is that it's important to state that the *variance* is a polynomial of degree **at most** 3. As written, the first paragraph seems to suggest that the variance is polynomial of degree 3, which is incorrect.

Comment: @jbowman: by the way, at the stage of the reasoning where it appears, the polynomial is deemed to be cubic. Only later can you see that it is incomplete.

Comment: @whuber - AFAICT, you are writing his answer for him.  He doesn't say that the variance is at most a cubic polynomial, he says it must be a cubic polynomial.  He doesn't say that the squared deviations are linear in $p$, therefore..., he makes a statement that could apply to any variance calculation at all, as all variance calculations are weighted sums of squared deviations...   I don't mind suggesting substantial edits and clarifications in comments, of course, but at the time of my reading... and do note I'm not the one who downvoted the answer, so I'm not the only one who didn't like it.

Answer (score 3):

The variance of a random variable is defined to be the expected value of the squared deviation of that variable from the mean.  In order to calculate it, we first need to know the mean of a Bernoulli variate with probability $p$:

$$\mathbb{E}(x) = 0\cdot(1-p) + 1\cdot p = p$$

as the probability of seeing a $1$ is $p$ and the probability of seeing a $0$ is therefore $1-p$.

Now for the expected value of the squared deviations from the mean:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}(x-p)^2 &=& (0-p)^2\cdot(1-p) + (1-p)^2\cdot p \\
&=& p^2(1-p)+(1-p)^2p\\
&=&p(1-p)\cdot[p+(1-p)]\\
&=&p(1-p)
\end{eqnarray}$$

As for the Binomial case - the Bernoulli case with multiple observations - we know that the variance of the sum of independent variables is equal to the sum of the variances of the independent variables.  In this case, all those independent variables have the same variance, so the sum is just $N$ times the variance:

$$\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^N\text{Var}(x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^Np(1-p) =Np(1-p) $$

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Extremely clear and to the point. It's more appreciated than you know! Have a wonderful day.

Comment: Thank you: this helps us appreciate what @Yves Daoust accomplished in their original answer.  They arrived at the same conclusion *without any algebraic calculation at all.*  Although there's nothing wrong with plugging in the definitions and turning the algorithmic handle, it's often the case that solutions arrived at through basic principles and little or no calculation provide special insight.